# oozie hive hadoop jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, sqoop, oozie

hi i am able to run a hive command in hive terminal but when i try to run it in through oozie i am unable to run it getting some error ans log file looks like below

```
2013-03-21 11:55:48,973  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[biadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W] ACTION[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node] Start action [0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2013-03-21 11:55:57,940  WARN HiveActionExecutor:542 - USER[biadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W] ACTION[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node] credentials is null for the action
2013-03-21 11:55:57,940  WARN HiveActionExecutor:542 - USER[biadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W] ACTION[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node] Could not find credentials properties for: null
2013-03-21 11:56:04,940  INFO HiveActionExecutor:539 - USER[biadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W] ACTION[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node] checking action, external ID [job_201303141654_0020] status [RUNNING]
2013-03-21 11:56:04,955  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[biadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W] ACTION[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node] [***0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node***]Action status=RUNNING
2013-03-21 11:56:05,334  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[biadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W] ACTION[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node] [***0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node***]Action updated in DB!
2013-03-21 11:56:33,520  INFO CallbackServlet:539 - USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W] ACTION[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node] callback for action [0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node]
2013-03-21 11:56:34,214  INFO HiveActionExecutor:539 - USER[biadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W] ACTION[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node] action completed, external ID [job_201303141654_0020]
2013-03-21 11:56:34,365  WARN HiveActionExecutor:542 - USER[biadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W] ACTION[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [10]
2013-03-21 11:56:35,059  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[biadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W] ACTION[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W@hive-node] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
2013-03-21 11:56:35,364  WARN CoordActionUpdateXCommand:542 - USER[biadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000005-130314190356094-oozie-biad-W] ACTION[-] E1100: Command precondition does not hold before execution, [, coord action is null], Error Code: E1100
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the Oozie job log which often doesn't provide enough information for you to find the root of your problem. You should look at the task log for the map reduce job. The easiest way to find it is to go to the Oozie Web Console (ie, http://example.example.com:11000/oozie/), double click on the oozie job in question to open it's job info, on the job info tab double click on the failed Hive action. On the action into tab there should be a console URL field. Open that address and click the links to find more info about the tasks (even successful ones since oozie can swallow the hive failure and report success to the task tracker. The useful logs have always been in a successful map task in my experience). Look at the logs and hopefully, but no necessarily, you will find something which will narrow it down from "hive failed."

This is not real answer to the question, so if anyone wants to post this as a comment and flag this answer for deletion please do.

Answer (score 0):

Error is from Oozie, workflow did not launched by coordinator i.e, if you started Oozie with root user stop the service and restart the oozie with User which you installed Oozie. Now re-run the workflow.

This would solve your problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Above error is because, you used a mismatched versions of hadoop and hive. To clear this error  rebuild oozie with required versions.
To rebuild oozie with requied version, edit pom.xml file in OOZIE_HOME.

```
<hadoop.version>x.x.x</hadoop.version>
 <hive.version>0.x.x</hive.version>
 <pig.version>0.x.x</pig.version>
```

After editing pom file, run OOZIE_HOME/bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests.